# removing data from NeDB database

Tags: javascript, database, embedded-database, nedb

this is my order to delete a data from my db

`chats.remove({ _id: chatId }, {}, function (err, numRemoved)  // chatId = 1001131507377`

the database before running the remove order

`{"_id":1001131507377,"chatTitle":"test group","AddedBy":"159263523 - @rrbot - Abd"}`

the data base after running the remove order

`{"_id":1001131507377,"chatTitle":"test group","AddedBy":"159263523 - @rrbot - Abd"}`
`{"$$deleted":true,"_id":1001131507377}`

it passes and doesn't show any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NeDB is working correctly.  Updates to data are appended at the end of the file until NeDB "compacts" the data.

You can manually compact the data with the command: chats.persistence.compactDatafile()

For more information see:
https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#persistence